# Interbase Server refuses to start

Tags: interbase

I am using the Interbase server developer instance quite a long time without any problem, but suddenly it refuses to start.

The guardian starts fine but the server intitiates and after a few seconds stops and the guardian also stops.

Anyone can help me with this issue?

Follows image of Task Manager services.

[image: Task Manager services]

Note: "parado" means sttoped

Comment: Perhaps the first thing to check is the event log (and whatever other logs Interbase might create).

Comment: Thanks mustaccio. Please, tell where I can check the event log

Comment: Depending on what version of Windows you have...  Look for a `Application` in teh tree on the left and search for interbase.  Or zero down on the time it happens

Comment: I could not find any event log.Turns out that I'm receiving message "...target machine actively refused connection"

Comment: I'v checked Windows Firewall: all permissions are granted and necessary rules are applied.

What else could it be?